# Cannot Transfer files from my mac to VM instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have managed to set up a VM instance on Google cloud platform using the following instructions:

https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52

I am then able to run a Jupyter notebook as per the instructions.

Now I want to be able to use my own data in the notebook....this is where I am really struggling. I downloaded the Cloud SDK onto my mac and ran this from the terminal (as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files)

My-MacBook-Air:~ me$  gcloud compute scp /Users/me/Desktop/my_data.csv aml-test:~/amlfolder

where aml-test is the name of my instance and amlfolder a folder I created on the VM instance. I don't get any error messages and it seems to work (the terminal displays the following after I run it >> 100%   66MB   1.0MB/s   01:03 )

However when I connect to my VM instance via the SSH button on the google console and type

cd amlfolder
ls

I cannot see any files! (nor can I see them from the jupyter notebook homepage)

I cannot figure out how to use my own data in a python jupyter notebook on a GCP VM instance. I have been trying/googling for an entire day. As you might have guessed I'm a complete newbie to GCP (and cd, ls and mkdir is the extent of my linux command knowledge!)

I also tried using Google Cloud Storage - I uploaded the data into a google storage bucket (as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) but don't know how to complete the last step '4. On your instance, download files from the bucket.'

If anyone can figure out what i am doing wrong, or an easier method to get my own data running into a python jupyter notebook on GCP than using gcloud scp command please help!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely try writing

`pwd`

to verify you're in the path you think you are, there's a chance that your scp command and the console SSH command login as different users.

To copy data from a bucket to the instance, do

`gsutil cp gcs://bucket-name/you-file .`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [gcloud compute docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#POSITIONAL-ARGUMENTS) , `gcloud compute scp /Users/me/Desktop/my_data.csv aml-test:~/amlfolder` will use your local environment username, so the tilde in your command refers to the home directory of a username that is the same name as your local.

But when you [SSH from the Browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#login_username) as you can see from docs that your Gmail username will be used.

So, you should check the home directory of the user used by `gcloud compute scp ...` command.

The easiest way to check, SSH to your VM and run

```
ls /home/ --recursive
```